# Display WAV file pitch

Tags: wav, pitch-tracking, audio

I'm new to the audio world, and I've been assigned a task I'm not sure how to deal with.
I need to display a graph representing the pitch of a WAV file. The WAV file can be polyphonic, and then I need to display the pitch graph of the dominant (read: with the strongest volume) instrument (or human voice singing).
I'm quite familiar with .NET, and knows next to nothing in C, C++, Java.

I started a research in the web, and from what I understood pitch detection of polyphonic WAV files is a not solved problem, but I don't need the exact pitch, just to know if it's higher from the next one, and what is its length.

My questions are:

1. Where should I start for learning the theory behind this task? Are there any recommended books for that?
2. Is there any API/tool that can do that?

Thanks,

ML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fourier Analysis to extract the constituent frequencies of the wave. Here's a related SO question: [Fast Fourier Transform in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c)

Comment: I'm concerned about the polyphonic nature of the WAV file.
Can FFT help me isolate the most dominant intrument / voice?

Comment: Well FFT will give you the dominant frequency in a fragment of wave - so if you have three instruments all producing middle C (whether as their fundamental frequency or harmonics) FFT won't tell you which instrument is the loudest but it will tell you that middle C is the loudest frequency in the sample.

Comment: I assume you've seen a 'spectrum analyser' - FFT will give you that.

Answer (score 1):

I started on signal processing with [Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/).  You can buy the book printed for around $30, or download the pdf for free.  It's written for non-scientists, and contains a great deal of information to get you up and running with various signal processing techniques.

FFT (fast fourier transforms) will convert a time vs amplitude signal into a frequency (bins) vs the intensity (energy).  You can go from frequency to a note via [standard charts](http://educate-yourself.org/lte/freqchartmusicalnotes28dec07.shtml) found on a lot of websites.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a somewhat related project.  You'll want to investigate fast fourier transforms.  I can recommend this [project written in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx) - it's written as a guitar tuner but it can be easily modified to your purpose.

This however won't do multi-pitch.  There is a product called "[celemony](http://www.celemony.com/cms/)" which claims to have this ability using "Direct Note Access (DNA)".  Their technology is understandably closed source, but you may be able to license it at the right price.