# C# library to do fft and ifft?

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

is there a free c# library to do the fast fourier transform and its inverse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast fourier transform in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An implementation of the fast Fourier transform (FFT) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/an-implementation-of-the-fast-fourier-transform-fft-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks m8.
But you know if any of those libs make the ifft?

Comment: The AForge solution at the top can do both forwards and reverse FFT, which I'm guessing is the same thing? Recently used the FFT class in there in a project, and it worked good.

Comment: Math.Net does for sure. http://mathnet.opensourcedotnet.info/doc/IridiumFFT.ashx

Comment: CenterSpace's NMath does inverse FFT's and forward FFT's for any input data length.

Comment: Math.NET only works for integral-power-of-two length inputs.

Comment: Update: Newer Math.NET Numerics versions do support arbitrary length inputs

Answer (score 3):

Both Math.NET and Aforce are based on the Exocortex.DSP library.  http://www.exocortex.org/dsp

Comment: Exocortex.org/dsp hasn't had a release in 6 years.  I wouldn't use it in an important project.

Comment: Paul since your company is selling software that competes with Exocortex DSP it would make sense that you would seed FUD about it.  Not ethical, but understandable on your part.

Comment: Exocortex was one of the libraries I tried before writing (and commercializing) my own C# FFT. IIRC, I didn't use it because it was buggy and very limited (only worked for a few transform sizes).

Comment: Jon Harrop, as the author of Exocortex.DSP, I have to say that yes it is limited to powers of 2, but it isn't buggy.  It has been deployed all over the place with a lot of success.