# Can't get Exocortex FFT to work

Tags: c#, fft, vibration

I'm writing an application that will analyze data from an accelerometer. One of the most important algorithms for this is obviously the FFT, and after much looking I found that Exocortexs library is one of the best for this.

Anyway, when I try to implement it I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Exocortex.DSP.v1.dll

Additional information: must be a power of 2
```

Here's the code:

```
class FFT
    {
        public Exocortex.DSP.ComplexF[] FourierTransform(List<double> vector)
        {
            //Dictionary<string, List<double>>

            int vectorLength = vector.Count;
            Exocortex.DSP.ComplexF[] complexData = new Exocortex.DSP.ComplexF[vectorLength];

            for (int i = 0; i < vectorLength; ++i)
            {
                complexData[i].Re = Convert.ToSingle(vector[i]); // Add your real part here
            //    complexData[i].Im = 2; // Add your imaginary part here
            }

            Exocortex.DSP.Fourier.FFT(complexData, Exocortex.DSP.FourierDirection.Forward);

            return complexData;
```

(This is really just a version of this example: [Fast Fourier Transform in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873725/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp)).

The problem might be as simple as the imaginary part of the acceleration since I assume this kind of data is only real but the answer, the FFT that is, is imaginary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and suggest that your *vectorLength* variable is **not** a `a power of 2`.

Try cropping your data such that its new length `L = N^2, where integer N > 1.`
Does that get ride of the exception?

Are you expecting your signal to be periodic in nature? Is it attached to some mechanism rotating/shaking at fairly steady frequency? If not, what would you hope to get out of using an FFT?

Comment: Many thanks @FredrikRedin, I feel so of stupid but of course that's the problem. The exception disappeared and the algorithm seems to work as expected! What I'm trying to do is find faults of machinery, and then FFT is very useful since most faults (unbalance, bearing faults and so forth) could be find as multiples of the RPM.

Comment: The FFT is a great choice for your task! PS: I did my master thesis on just that (!): predicting the deterioration of mechanical gears using signal processing techniques. Tip: Don't ignore sidebands around your fundamental harmonic frequency (multiples of RPM), they may be the result of phase modulation which you would expect to arise when timing of meshing/cogging of rotational components becomes uneven (read: increased variance) due to deterioration. PPS: FFTW is another great FFT library used by many. http://www.fftw.org/