# Fast Fourier Transformation in WinForms

Tags: c++, winforms, fft

I write an application on VS-2008 (WinForms, C++) 
Need a Fast Fourier transformation Library. 
Can anybody advise a good one?

Comment: Check out intel MKL (Math Kernel Library) - it has both linear algebra and FFT support

Comment: You are using .NET so you don't care about the language.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp

Comment: Probably [this](http://ilnumerics.net/) library will do the job.

Comment: Here is some [sample code](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementation-of-fast-fourier-transform-for-image-processing-in-directx-10) for DirectX 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend FFTW over anything else.  It is fast, reliable, widely used, portable.  Yes, you will have to call from managed code into unmanaged code.

Comment: FFTW is great if you need peak performance.  If not, there seems to be fft source code for .net that comes without FFTW's license restrictions or fairly high fee.