# Remove a specific frequency from mp3 file

Tags: c#, windows, audio, mp3

I'm wondering what methods are available to remove a specific frequency from an mp3 or wav file using C#.

I'm hoping for a library or example where I can input an mp3 ( or any other format, ill convert my soundtrack to whatever format is needed) and a single frequency (or list of frequencies) to remove from the file.

If there are no methods of doing this in C# I'll accept solutions using other languages as well.

I prefeer solutions using free or open source libraries.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: As an anti-piracy measure some albums released this year sample brown noise

Comment: look into FFT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp

Comment: What you need to do is build a filter.  Beware though that digital music watermarking isn't this simple.  If you are trying to remove a watermark, you are going to very disappointed to find out that it is impossible without knowing the original keys.  Most of the watermarking services use spread spectrum, making things very difficult.

Comment: I would not recommend an FFT. Why? Unless you are dealing with short files, you will have to chunk the data and perform OLA (overlap/Add) on each chunk. Generally, for something like this, time-domain filtering is the solution, but it depends on how specific the frequencies you want to eliminate are.

Comment: This has nothing to do with removing any type of piracy protection. Im trying to remove a constant high pitch noise from many interview recordings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest converting your MP3 to PCM, then using a time-domain filter.

A basic approach would be to use the notch filter described here:

http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

with an implementation like this:

http://musicdsp.org/showArchiveComment.php?ArchiveID=174