# C# FFT Library Need to know

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, fft, ifft

I am solving problem related with FFT. I am having situation like, I have to forward incoming data stream towards FFT Library function or FFT routine that can transform the time domain data to frequency domain data.

Which Library in C# do I need to use ? Do Microsoft provided this ? or I need to use some third party libraries for this?

Comment: what specific functions do you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp

Comment: To Transform incoming real time data to frequency domain data
like 
I may have an array [1045789,445789,635454,-987774,6523457,897456] which can transform to Complex data after calling like FFT( array, out Complex data )......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at this library:

http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

I use this library a fair bit, though I've never used its FFT functions:

http://www.mathdotnet.com/

There is also this library which seems to get alot of mention, but I've never used it so I can't comment on it's quality.

http://www.exocortex.org/dsp/

Comment: Thanks Cholida..
I think .NET aforge will work...I am going to try this!!

Answer (score 3):

An old question but it still shows up in Google results.

A very modern and fast C# / .NET FFT library is available at,

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1107480/dsplib-fft-dft-fourier-transform-library-for-net

Hope this helps