# comparing 2 audio files to detect if it is the same speaker, in c#

Tags: c#, audio, fft

I have 2 audio .wav files recorded by the the same person with the same word. Each audio file has a format of 16bit, 44.1kHz and is a mono channel. I would like to know how to compare these 2 audio files if it is by the same person. What I know is to process the files to produce a floating point result of values between -1 and 1 and apply fft on it  and compare the frequency. What I would like to know is how to compare the pcm of the audio files, prefably with the  code which shows the comparison and if possible the steps before that(processing to become values btw 1 and -1).Thanks.
Im relatively new in this area so I would appreciate If u guys would help me out. I'm currently using a metro application in vs. I would prefer not to use any library like naudio or bass.net but I would still accept any answer.
A step by step solution starting from utilizing the .wav file is much appreciated.
I have been trying to search topics related to what I'm doing but what I have found are small parts of it.

Comment: I believe cross-posing is discouraged: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/comparing-2-audio-files-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect whether the files are produced by the same person then this is *way* more complex than just comparing the waveforms, or even doing a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). This is the area of Speaker Recognition, and there have been many research papers on this subject. It's not a simple task, and in order to get anywhere you'll need to have a grounding in Signal Processing techniques (unless you can find a library to do it for you).  A good place to start reading about it is the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_recognition).

This [article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Speaker_recognition) gives an overview of some techniques. Common approaches include the use of [Hidden Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) and [Mel-frequency Cepstral Coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum).

Answer (score -2):

You don't want to compare it in .wav format. Do a [An implementation of the fast Fourier transform (FFT) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp)
 and compare the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram.