# JavaScript code in Windows Store app written in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm writing an application for Windows Store using C#/XAML. And I haven't found a library to use FFT in C#, but in JavaScript though. Can I call JavaScript functions from my C# code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Use **either** `C#` or `JS`.

---

There might be a workaround of hosting a simple web browser in your app and using `JS` inside it but I would recommend avoiding that.

---

PS. if by FFT you mean Fast fourier transform then maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/170413/885318

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering, because have found couple ways how to insert JavaScript code into C#, but non of them seem to work correctly on complex programs. 
I was looking for Fast Fourier Transform, thanks again.

Comment: Answer is wrong. You can create a Windows Runtime Component project in either C#, C++ or JS - these can all be consumed by Store projects in any language.

Comment: That's not calling JS functions from C#.