# Is there any way to use Youtube API stream to do fast fourier transform with C# application

Tags: c#, youtube-api, fft

Say you link to a video on Youtube with a C# application using Youtube API.
Is there any way to deal with the video Flash so it's look like doing fast fourier transform on realtime?

Comment: What are you currently doing? Could you share code example? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my trouble is not how to do fft, I wonder to know whether we can get the music information, like .mp3, without download when watching youtube video streaming.